# Enviar dados de Login Externo para Controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, oauth2

Preciso realizar login através do Facebook,  tenho a pagina de login, que renderiza uma `@Html.Partial` *_LoginExternal* Segue o código das duas:

```
@using EuVotoAf.Models
@model LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}


<div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:50px" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">Entrar</div>
            <div style="float:right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
        </div>

        <section id="loginForm" style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>

                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email" })
                    </div>

                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Senha" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @type = "checkbox", @name = "remember", @value = "1" })
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                        <!-- Button -->

                        <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                            <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-success" /> <br />

                            <div style="padding-top:2px">
                                <section id="socialLoginForm">
                                    @Html.Partial("_LoginExternal", new ExternalLoginListViewModel { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
                                </section>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12 control">
                            <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top:15px; font-size:85%">
                                Não possui uma conta ? @Html.ActionLink("Registrar", "Register")
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

**_LoginExternal**

```
@model EuVotoAf.Models.ExternalLoginListViewModel
@using Microsoft.Owin.Security

@{
    var loginProviders = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes();
    using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div id="socialLoginList">
            <p>
                @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders) { 
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType" title="Log in using your @p.Caption account">@p.AuthenticationType</button>
                }
            </p>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Porém ao clicar no botão `submit` da `_LoginExternal` nada acontece, e o método não chega nem a entrar no `controller` que o `@Html.BeginForm`  é vinculado.
testei e me certifiquei que autenticação está correta. Ele carrega os dados nos trechos:

```
@{
    var loginProviders = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes();
    using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div id="socialLoginList">
            <p>
                @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders) { 
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType" title="Log in using your @p.Caption account">@p.AuthenticationType</button>
                }
            </p>
        </div>
    }
}
```

E não envia para o `AccountController`

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    // Request a redirect to the external login provider
    return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
}
```

O que neste código está errado, ou faltando ?

Comment: Ja pensou em usar  o identity ele cuida de toda autenticação usando facebook, twitter, github etc... [Link](https://www.asp.net/identity)

Comment: @MarcoViniciusSoaresDalalba estou usando o Identity, a autenticação está OK. Apenas os dados vindos da autenticação, não vão para o controller informado na pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com a ajuda do [Jbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/18246/jbueno), cheguei a seguinte respota.

Bem, esse trata-se um caso de especificação do `HTML` onde não é possível, possuir um `form` dentro de outro.

O que precisa ser feito neste caso, é simplesmente trocar o local onde está declarado a `div` que é renderizada da `@Html.Partial`

```
<div style="padding-top:2px">
  <section id="socialLoginForm">
    @Html.Partial("_LoginExternal", new ExternalLoginListViewModel { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
  </section>
</div>
```

que rend. Ou seja, o `Html` da pagina de login, deve ser algo parecido com isso:

```
@using EuVotoAf.Models
@model LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}


<div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:50px" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">Entrar</div>
            <div style="float:right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
        </div>

        <section id="loginForm" style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>

                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email" })
                    </div>

                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Senha" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @type = "checkbox", @name = "remember", @value = "1" })
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                        <!-- Button -->

                        <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                            <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-success" /> <br />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12 control">
                            <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top:15px; font-size:85%">
                                Não possui uma conta ? @Html.ActionLink("Registrar", "Register")
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            }
            <div style="padding-top:2px">
                <section id="socialLoginForm">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginExternal", new ExternalLoginListViewModel { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
                </section>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Com isso poderá ser feito o login normalmente. Claro, desde que atenda os requisitos para utilizar login `externo`.